# BizTalk Pipeline Components Extensions Utility Pack: Zip Pipeline Component

Tags: biztalk

I am trying to use the Zip pipeline component in BizTalk Server 2016 which is mentioned in this link https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2018/10/03/biztalk-pipeline-components-extensions-utility-pack-zip-pipeline-component/

I am doing a simple scenario where i have created a Receive Location and Send Port (subscribes to the message based on Receive port filter). I used the Zip Pipeline Component in the send pipeline.

Just dropped 2 files in Receive Location , the zipping looks like not working. Its producing two files in zip extension but corrupted one not able to open the zip. It actually need to create one zip file with two files in it.

Any Advise on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include multiple files in an archive, you would need to use the MultiPartMsgZip version.  Then you would have to assemble the MPM prior to that, in an Orchestration for example.

What exactly do you mean 'corrupt'?  I'm quite confident the component produces correct zip output.

Comment: When i try to use the zip pipeline , it creating the zip file but when i try to open no file is inside and its giving an error saying "Invalid File" . To your point. My scenerio is I have 3 files in a folder which i need to zip in one archive. Can you suggest how it needs to be done ? Do i need to use Convoys ? Without Orchestration can i do ?

Comment: @sukra BizTalk is great, but maybe this is something that's better done with a script and Task?